# this should be possible using only dictionaries and lists (instead of the range of if statements), any ideas?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying to write a program that will ask the user to input a shape and then return the area. I figured it out using functions and if statements, but the code is supposed to only use the dictionary shown below and the splat operator to do the same, whereas I can only figure it out using if statements. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?
What I initially tried doing was storing the input functions within the dictionary so that when the dictionary printed I was hoping the input options would be run too, but that didn't work. Then I tried storing the input in the actual functions, with the functions in the dictionary, and tried to call the functions as values in the dictionary, which also didn't work.
Thanks so much in advance!

```
     import math

     #function to calculate the area of a circle
     def circle_area(r):
         area = 3.14 * (r ** 2)
         msg = f"The area of your circle is {area: .2f}."
         return(msg)

     #function to calculate the area of a sector
     def sector_area(r, angle):
         area = (angle / 360) * math.pi * (r ** 2)
         msg = f"The area of your sector is {area: .2f}."
         return(msg)

     #function to calculate the area of a square
     def square_area(l):
         area = l ** 2
         msg = f"The area of your square is {area: .2f}."
         return(msg)

     #function to calculate the area of a rectangle
     def rectangle_area(l, w):
         area = l * w
         msg = f"The area of your rectangle is {area: .2f}."
         return(msg)

     #function to calculate the area of a kite
     def kite_area(l, w):
         area = (l * w) / 2
         msg = f"The area of your kite is {area: .2f}."
         return(msg)

     #shapes dictionary to info needed for each calculation
     shapes = {"circle": [circle_area, ["r"]],
               "sector": [sector_area, ["angle", "r"]],
               "square": [square_area, ["l"]],
               "rectangle": [rectangle_area, ["l", "w"]], 
              "kite": [kite_area, ["l", "w"]]
               }

     #request for user input to determine shape type for calculations
     shape = input("What shape would you like to find the area of? ")

   if shape in shapes.keys():

         if shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
             r = int(input("Please enter radius: "))
             print(circle_area(r))
             print()
    
         elif shape == "sector" or shape == "Sector":
             r = int(input("Please enter radius: "))
             angle = int(input("Please enter theta (deg): "))
             print(sector_area(r, angle))
             print()

         elif shape == "square" or shape == "Square":
             l = int(input("Please enter length: "))
             print(square_area)
             print()

         elif shape == "rectangle" or shape == "Rectangle":
             l = int(input("Please enter length: "))
             w = int(input("Please enter width: "))
             print(rectangle_area(l, w))
             print()

         elif shape == "kite" or shape == "Kite":
             l = int(input("Please enter length: "))
             w = int(input("Please enter width: "))
             print(kite_area(l, w))
             print()


     else:
         msg = f"{shape} is not supported."
         print(msg)
```

Comment: What is your attempt at resolving that part of your homework? What worked and didn't work? As it is, you're basically just asking for homework completion.

Comment: Also, `shape in shapes.keys()` is a relic from Python 2; don't do that. Just do `shape in shapes`. Additionally, you've explicitly handled input with a capitalized first letter within that `if` block, but it doesn't matter because those will already fail when you check if they're in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the list into the function and list of argument names. Use the argument names to prompt for all the inputs, and put those responses into a list.

Then you can call the function with those arguments using the splat operator.

```
if shape.lower() in shapes: # don't need to use shapes.keys() here
    func, argnames = shapes[shape.lower()]
    args = [int(input(f'Please enter {arg}: ')) for arg in argnames]
    print(func(*args))
else:
    print(f"{shape} is not supported")
```